# How to get accessibilityIdentifier from #selector

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift3, selector, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to pass the accessibilityIdentifier of the imageView I created, but it doesn't seem to do so (I have successfully set the accessiblityIdentifier btw).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this once :

Set isAccessibilityElement as true in your imageView.
Like this:

Before taking Identifier in your code put this and than check.

image.isAccessibilityElement = true